# Node JS: calculating number working in each month between a two dates

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I am trying to develop a code to generate number of working days in each month between two selected dates:

Eg: Start Date is 20-Oct-2022 and End Date is 14-Feb-2023.

I am able to generate net working days between two dates, however not for each month between the two dates.

I am expecting the code to provide output as:
Net working days in
Oct'22 is 8,
Nov'22 is 21,
Jan'23 is 22 and
Feb'22 is 10.

Answer (score 0):

```
var startDate = new Date('20/10/2022');
var endDate = new Date('14/02/2023');
var numOfDates = getBusinessDatesCount(startDate,endDate);

function getBusinessDatesCount(startDate, endDate) {
 let count = 0;
const curDate = new Date(startDate.getTime());
while (curDate <= endDate) {
    const dayOfWeek = curDate.getDay();
    if(dayOfWeek !== 0 && dayOfWeek !== 6) count++;
    curDate.setDate(curDate.getDate() + 1);
 }
 return count;
}
```

like in above example you can calculate number of working days between two dates.

Comment: Getting below response :"data": {
    "numOfDates": 84
  }

Comment: I need the split of 84 into each months

Comment: you can split wise it in the loop 
store the expected things in array of months